# FBSdk Share dialog when FB App is not installed

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer, facebook-sdk-3.0

I've been following Facebook code sample "FBShareSample" to create a share dialog,
The example handles the fallback for user without FB App installed.

Everything is working well with FB App but when I get to the fallback the UI in my app look different from the one in FBDemo (navigation bar, buttons etc.) 
In addition the friends button is not active.

Am I missing some kind of configuration in my iOS client? Is it somehting that need to be configured on my App page on FB?

[image: Share Dialog in my App (left) and in FB Example(right)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Charles to analyse the request and response and the only difference between FB sample code and my code was the userAgent string.

The problem was resolved by removing from the UserAgent parameter the string: " webView", for some reason this specific string caused FB to return a different layout/CSS page when this parameter was present.